# Selenium + Webdriver return same information as first get after repeated gets

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Repeated calls to the same URL using Python Selenium and a webdriver (geckodriver or Chrome driver) return the proper information the first time the program is run. But each successive runs even after a wait of 60 secs and even a reboot still returns the information from the first get URL.

Below is the code for the start of a program to scrape the odds at a racetrack every minute. The sleep in the code is less for testing purposes.

```
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver

#url = "https://www.drf.com/live_odds/winodds/track/DED/USA/3/D"
#url = "https://www.drf.com/live_odds/winodds/track/TAM/USA/10/D"
#url = "https://www.drf.com/live_odds/winodds/track/AUS-MNG/AUS/5/D"
#url = "https://www.drf.com/live_odds/winodds/track/AUS-AUC/AUS/2/D"
url = "https://www.drf.com/live_odds/winodds/track/SA/USA/5/D"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(50)
#url = "https://www.drf.com/live_odds/winodds/track/AQU/USA/7/D"
#url = "https://www.drf.com/live_odds/winodds/track/LA/USA/4/D"

driver.close()
driver.quit()

#os.system(killall "Chrome")
```

At first I thought the problem was in my requests so I transferred to Selenium and geckodriver and later Chrome Driver. Then it worked. The first time I got the URL the proper information was returned. The second time I used the same URL and did a get- the odds will eventually change - I still got the results from the first get URL. Even when I run the program again I still get the same results as the first get URL. But if I run Chrome without Selenium and go to the same URL I then get the proper updated odds. Also running Chrome without Selenium the odds are displayed horizontally across the page while the odds are displayed in a column when I run Selenium and the Chrome driver. I know there are often compatibility issues, but I downloaded Selenium and the drivers within the last two or three weeks.

This program will be far from accurate if you run it when SA - Santa Anita Racetrack is not running and in this code it would be race number 5. You can easily change the race number that matches the current race. And you can change the track by going to www.drf.com and then going to entries and clicking on Live Odds. There you will see a list of tracks and you can click on one and there you will see the appropriate URL. Paste that into the program and assign it as the new URL. Again you will see that the screen returned is correct but you can run the program again and again and you will only get the results obtained in the first screen. You will not get the new odds that you will get if you run Chrome without Selenium. Is there some references stuck in a buffer or is the website trying to prohibit continuous web scraping of the odds. I also tried rebooting but still got the old results from the URL when running again Selenium and Chrome Driver.

Again if I run just Chrome I get the new updates. Could this mean there is some reference to the original request that must be saved on the disk as all references in memory would be erased with a reboot? Could this involve a socket reference?

Comment: Slightly tongue in cheek, but http://shouldiblamecaching.com ... My guess would be that Chrome keeps the page cached on disk and requires an explicit reload.